# C# Define override method in different assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class library that i have built that consists of a number of classes that inherit from a single base class.

there is a virtual method defined on the base class called Process which essentially will process the content of the class structure into the application.

There is messaging going between different components (servers) of the application, and they are passing and receiving messages of the base class type, and then calling Process()

Where i have gotten stuck is that i need to be able to override the Process() method in the other parts of the application, i.e. in different assemblies without deriving another type from it.

From what i have read this seems not possible, so looking at if using interfaces would solve the issue?

EDIT:

What i failed to mention in the question is the each derived class of the base class needs to have a different implementation of Process() depending on the functionality required by that class.

For example:

```
class First : BaseClass
{
  override void Process()
  {
    //do something
  }
}

class Second : BaseClass
{
  override void Process()
  {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

the code in the override process methods need to be in different assemblies, due to the fact that this code will be referencing other external sources based on the class it belongs to that i do not want to propagate across the entire application.

Just for clarification i do have access and can change the library class if required.

I have been doing some further reading and it would appear using delegates could solve this issue.. thoughts?

Comment: Why can't You derive from that class? If You wan't use interfaces You would also need to touch the library class. I guess You are not allowed for that neither.

Comment: So, your question is basically how to override a method from a class that is not your base class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interfaces, specifically the **Strategy Pattern** would solve your issue.

```
public interface IProcessStrategy
{
    void Process();
}

public class ProcessService
{
    public void DoProcess( IProcessStrategy strategy )
    {
        ...whatever
        strategy.Process();
        ...whatever else
    }
}
```

By separating the processing to its own abstraction, you allow creating multiple strategies and technically it doesn't matter if a strategy is defined in the same or a different assembly.

**Update:** I guess I finally know what you are up to and my suggestion is to have an interface you can inject but still have a default implementation.

```
public interface IProcessStrategy
{
    void Process();
}

public class BaseClass
{
    private IProcessStrategy _strategy;

    public void Process()
    {
        // this is where the real "override" happens
        if ( _strategy == null )
        {
            // default implementation
            ...
        }
        else
            // overridden
            _strategy.Process();
    }

    public void OverrideWith( IProcessStrategy strategy )
    {
        this._strategy = strategy;
    }
```

The way you use it:

```
 BaseClass f = new BaseClass();
 f.Process(); // uses the default implementation
```

and somewhere else

```
 BaseClass f = new BaseClass();
 IProcessStrategy p = new First();

 // override
 f.OverrideWith( p );
 f.Process(); // overridden with a new implementation
```

Note then that the overridden implementation, the `First`can be defined anywhere, including a different assembly, it just has to implement the common interface.

Comment: thanks for this, this does appear to answer the question, the only issue is that i neglected to mention a key part in the question. i have updated.

Comment: Reading your comment few times and still can't decide whether it changes anything in my answer. I guess your description is still a little vague.

Comment: i guess my real question is how i can define the different process methods for Classes First and Second. From what i can understand in your example, the same method would get called for both an invocation of First.Process() and Second.Process()

Comment: If you have two different implementations of the same interface, why would the same method be called?

Comment: i am a little weak when i comes to interfaces so guess i am just missing the  bits to complete the example. would you mind showing me how this could be applied to the code sample i added earlier? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Have you actually tried to place `First` and `Second` in different assemblies?

Comment: ah ok, i see where the confusion is now. So the example i gave above would all be in the same assembly, it is essentially a messaging library that is used to talk between two other applications.

what i want to do is be able to define the method content for Process() of either First or Second in App 1, and then define different content for Process() of First or Second in App 2

the reason behind this is that i do not want to expose all the dependencies that each application has to both App1 and App2

i have come to the conclusion that this is not possible and i will just have to live with it.

Comment: I get you now, finally. And I guess this is solvable the way I show you. You just need a **default** implementation of the interface so that you can override it but it is still there in case you don't override. Will edit my answer.